# How to create a buffer from points and a base map with different coordinate system on QGis?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, buffer

I've added some points from a CSV file by their coordinates using the WGS84. It fits perfectly with the shapefile i'm using as a basemap (Sirgas 2000). However, when I try to create a buffer zone around the points (to later intersect with the original shapefile), if I use the WGS projection it occupies all the screen and if I use the Sirgas 2000 it appears as a single circle in what I think to be a random place.

I've been doing this for quite a while on ArcMap, but I didn't have the need to use different coordinate systems. Perhaps I'm just missing something. Can someone bring a light into my problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Can you please [edit] your question to include some screenshots, and details on how you set your buffer?

Comment: The distance specified for buffer creation would be in the map units of the projection system of the layer. In what units (meters or degrees) do you want to give the buffer distance?

Comment: I'm following what I believe is a standard procedure to set a buffer... i've done that before.

Comment: I want to set my buffer with 1000m

Answer (score 1):

You would need to save your CSV file in a Projection system which uses meters as its map unit (for example - an applicable UTM for the area in your layer). Only then you should run the buffer function with the 'Distance' as 1000. This should create buffers as you desire.

Also note that any operation you want to perform afterwards between the two layers (like intersect) would require them both to be in the same projection system. So please take care of that.